# Updating ListView fragment when not focused

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I'm working on a tablet application with a ListView fragment on the left, and some other views including a SearchView (essentially a TextView) on the right. When the SearchView is focused, I want to update the data of the listview, but I can't.  If I **notifyDataSetChanged** on the UI thread, nothing happens. If I call **setAdapter()** again on my listview, the listview goes blank.

Only when I touch the listview again (it gets temporary focus again or something to cause getView() to be called on the adapter) does it get updated.

Anyone got an idea on how to fix this?

Min-Sdk and Target is 4.0.3.

Comment: You're using `SearchView` in the layout file?

Comment: Yes, the layout XML for the fragment.

Comment: What are you using to populate the list?  A Loader of some sort?

Comment: No, just populating a BaseAdapter manually to begin with, and then modifying the items in that adapter later. Very basic stuff really...

Comment: if you think its focus issue then you can call listview.requestFocus() before calling notifysetDataChanged()

Comment: More than a week later updated the code and it turns out that this problem no longer occurs. I've attempted lots of investigation to understand why, but I feel that the original question is now not relevant, and the problem never existed.  I originally posted as I felt that this issue if solved would be helpful to others.  What should I do with the question now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What now works for me is updating the data in the underlying adapter and then calling **notifyDataSetChanged** on that adapter, all from the UI thread.

I did not need to call **setAdapter** again on the listView.

Of course I had already tried all this before asking the question, so not sure what made it suddenly start working.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to call your *refresh* routine using `runOnUiThread()` ?

Reform your objects list, bind to a *new instance* of your adapter, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`and `setAdapter()` again in *refresh* routine would work.

Comment: Unfortunately I had already tried all this before asking the question. However, now everything seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a **ViewHolder** to handle updates in a ListView I think.

Comment: I already use ViewHolder in my getView() in my underlying adapter, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Call it inside the runOnUiThread method. Also add the new object to the adapter inside it.

Like that:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        chatListAdapter.add(message);
        chatListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```